# Why Spring AOP is not weaving external jars at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I have a java application build upon Spring 3. This project has another jar as a dependency.

This dependency contains a `@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect` class (lets say, `com.aspectprovider.aspects.MyAspect`). There's a `@Before` advice to weave a method from classes that implements the interface `Foo`. Something like:

```
@Before("execution(* com.project.Foo.save(..))")
```

The `Foo` interface can be inside the "project" or in another jar. It doesn't matter for this example.

My project contains classes that implements `Foo`. Those are the classes that I want it to be weaved, of course.

My Spring application context configuration file (`applicationContext.xml`) contains the line:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

I also declare the aspect as a bean, and inject some properties:

```
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.aspectprovider.aspects.MyAspect"
  factory-method="aspectOf" >
  <property name="someproperty" value="somevalue" />
</bean>
```

Trough logging I can see that `MyAspect` is instantiated and the properties are injected. But the method save is not intercepted. This is the problem.

If I copy the aspect classes from the jar to the application that has Spring, it works. When those aspects are contained in external jars, the method save is not intercepted. Any clues?

**edit: how I am calling Foo's save method:**

```
//in a JSF managed bean
@Inject
private Foo myFoo;  //there's a implementation of Foo in a package that spring is looking at. So it is injected correctly.

public String someAction() {
    myFoo.save("something"); //the @Before advice is only called if the class containing the aspect is not in an external jar
}


//in a class with a main method
void main(String[] ars) {
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    //right after the previous line, I can see in the log that MyAspect is instantiated.
    Foo myFoo = ac.getBean(Foo.class);
    myFoo.save("something"); //the @Before advice is only called if the class containing the aspect is not in an external jar
}
```

Basically, my `applicationContext.xml` has the following lines:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.project" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.aspectprovider.aspects" />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.aspectprovider.aspects.MyAspect" factory-method="aspectOf" >
    <property name="someproperty" value="somevalue" />
</bean>
```

I don't think I need to put anything like

```
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.project">
    <context:include-filter type="aspectj" expression="com.aspectprovider.aspects.*" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Comment: Are you running it under a J2EE environement?  Weblogic websphere jboss or even tomcat?

Comment: it's tomcat. but I have the same issue if I run through console, loading spring context "by hand".

Comment: How are you calling the `save` method in question? If you're not calling it through a reference that Spring is providing your code, *the pointcut will not be called*. The usual mistake is to call via `this` (explicitly or implicitly), which is a direct invocation on the wrapped instance and not on the bean itself.

Comment: Hi. Yes. I am calling trough a reference that spring is providing to me. Either by getBean or trough Spring web application context, with annotations. There's no new keyword in my code. I'm editing the post and adding how I am calling. I'm also fixing the aspect's package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up declaring the aspects in the spring's applicationContext xml config and removing the annotations.

What was working so far was using the aspectj plugin for maven, but everytime I changed a class in eclipse, I had to run `$ mvn compile` (because eclipse doesn't know the aspects, and was compiling the classes without them), and that's an awful thing to say to anybody that will use `MyAspect`.

Then I just created a config file and documented: to use `MyAspect`, just import this config rules to your spring's context configuration.

Comment: I am in the same situation as you were; but my aspect is annotation based, so would that be a problem? And don't we need to do load-time weaving in this situation?

Answer (score 9):

I have the same problem. I solved this problem packaging with maven. Check the `aspectj-maven-plugin` and option `weaveDependency`

http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/weaveJars.html

Comment: That's what I was doing (check [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956490/why-spring-aop-is-not-weaving-external-jars-at-runtime/6238001#6238001)), but still I had to compile it manually or using some external tool. I was looking for a load time weaving, not a compile time weaving.

Answer (score 6):

Considering it works perfectly fine when the classes are packaged with the application and spring I can only think it would be a classloading issue.

If it works fine when your bundled in your app then then when AOP scans all the classes that it will have to monitor then it is referencing the right classloader with all the right jars.  But now when you remove it and set it into a JAR it is scanning under the classloader with all of the other third party jars.

I am not 100% sure how it is mapped out but it could be something like this:

```
Bootstrap Classloader <- Third Party Classloader  <- Application Class Loader (with all your classes)
                              \                         \
                               aspectj.jar               spring.jar
```

If its aspect.jar is scanning under only its classloader then it will not be able to see 'all your classes'.  One way you can try confirming this is to get a heap dump of your app.  Run it against Eclipse MAT, Check out Class Loader explorer and look for the aspect classes.  If they do not reside under the same classloader as your application you would have to look at a way to have tomcat tell the third party libraries of the application classes.

Comment: so you are saying that the third party jars (including the one with the aspects) are loaded in a different classloader than the project's classes. And the aspectj only weaves the "main" classloader? is that it?

Comment: yea that is what I am suspecting.  You can test this by finding the name of a method within the third party library set and having AOP intercept that method call.  If that works then you are getting closer.

Comment: Good one (+1). It may be indeed a class loader issue. I moved one of  `Foo`'s implementations into `MyAspect`'s jar, then the `save()` method of this implementation was intercepted when I called it in the way described in the question. So, now that we are sure about it, is there anything that can be done?

Comment: Great news!  At this point you have to work with Tomcat's classloading model.  I did a quick search and people were referring to TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader (offered by spring).  I haven't worked with tomcat in resolving classloader issues, but you basically want tomcat and spring to be able to know about eachothers classes.  Configuration on this link may help http://datenschwanz.net/2009/12/21/load-time-weaving-with-spring-aspectj-and-tomcat/

Comment: For further debugging you can include -Dorg.aspectj.tracing.enabled=true as a start up parameter to get more information about what aspectj is doing

Comment: Working with Tomcat's classloading model will sure solve the issue. But that's the kind of thing that I am trying to avoid. I want to see if it's possible to distribute `MyAspect` in a jar to a client that uses Spring and tell him just to write simple configuration on his applicationContext (no aop.xml). Plus, I want to be able to test the aspects with jUnit. So far I am using eclipse (no plugins) + maven and running `$ mvn compile` every time I change any class...

Answer (score 2):

You might try aspectJ LTW instead of Spring AOP proxy. To do this add a aop.xml to your META-INF

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in this package -->
        <include within="org.springbyexample.aspectjLoadTimeWeaving.*" />
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- use only this aspect for weaving -->
        <aspect name="org.springbyexample.aspectjLoadTimeWeaving.PerformanceAdvice" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

And this is the spring portion of the config:

See here  for details : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

Comment: Thanks, but I already know about LTW, and I am trying to avoid for a couple of reasons that I don't think it's the time to discuss. Runtime weaving was working perfectly until now. The issue started when I separated the aspects to another jar.

Answer (score 0):

From AspectJ in action book:
aspects used with the proxy-based AOP (declared using @AspectJ
or XML-based syntax) are Spring beans and shouldn’t use the aspectOf() approach
to instantiation.

Declare it normally and see if it works out:

```
<bean id="myAspect" class="com.project.MyAspect">
  <property name="someproperty" value="somevalue" />
</bean>
```

Comment: well, actually if I don't use the `factory-method`, `MyAspect` is instantiated twice. I believe the first time is because of `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`. One thing or the other, still only works when `MyAspect` is not in an external jar.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at ApectWerks, it does load-time weaving:
http://aspectwerkz.codehaus.org/weaving.html