# spring aspect not applied if defined in an imported xml

Tags: spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have 2 JAR files, say A.jar and B.jar, A.jar contains a Spring XML, A.xml, that defines transaction related stuff.

```
<bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="lookUpDataSource" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="readAll" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="FooBarOperation"
            expression="execution(* com.foo.bar.service.*ServiceInterface.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="FooBarOperation" />
    </aop:config>
```

I have written a service in A.jar, com.foo.bar.service.AlphaServiceInterface and it does a DB transaction using Hibernate SQL. When I test this service using JUnit from A.jar, all is well, proxy is created by Spring and I am able to run the service call. Now, I am importing above Spring XML file in another Spring XML file, B.xml, placed in B.jar using

```
<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/A.xml"/>
```

I write exactly same junit test in B.jar and try to test it, Transaction context do not get created and I run in to following exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: createSQLQuery is not valid without active transaction

please note, this question is related to [Spring Aspect not executed when defined in other JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204374/spring-aspect-not-executed-when-defined-in-other-jar).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this was happening because of below in my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

After removing above line its working fine, I am yet to find out how agove was causing the problem though.