# Spring AOP issue with multi maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, aspectj-maven-plugin

Hi I am using a multi maven spring project 
with modules in POM

1. Bhoomi-domain-it
2. Bhoomi-data-it
3. Bhoomi-domain
4. Bhoomi-data
5. Bhoomi-presentation
6. Bhoomi-integration-consumer
7. Bhoomi-integration-provider

With individual `pom.xml`

I have created a LoggerAspect Class in `Bhoomi-presentation` module containing

```
@Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
```

Question is when i am building project(Bhoomi-presentation-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war) it is only logging logs of class files present in Bhoomi-presentation module not for other module

All other module present as a jar in lib of WAR

Please let me know if i forgot any configuration so that i can log all project logs

Comment: is there a separate spring context in each module? you might need to enable aop in each? or if there is one then the root one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204374/spring-aspect-not-executed-when-defined-in-other-jar

Answer (score 0):

```
I can think of something like this in XML( surely it can be done with annotations as well ) for creating common pointcuts spanning multiple modules

<aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="appPointcutServices" expression="bean(*Services)" />
        <aop:pointcut id="appPointcutDao" expression="bean(*Dao)" />
        <aop:pointcut id="appPointcutRepository" expression="bean(*Repository)" />
<aop:config>

& Then attach these pointcuts with your application defined Advisor
```